# Add event handler at runtime to a control where the body source code is stored in a variable

Tags: c#, reflection, event-handling, dynamicmethod

I need a little help!

I'm creating custom control at runtime, deserializing an xml which contains the info.
My custom controls have two properties, one with the name of an event, the second with the code to execute when the event raises (i.e. the method body).

I extract the values in two variables. What I need is to add and handler to my control at runtime for the event which execute the code stored in the variable.

```
string eventName = "Click";
string codeToRun= "MessageBox.Show(\"Hello!\");"
Type tControl = result.GetType();
EventInfo ev = tControl.GetEvent(eventName);
Type tDelegate = ev.EventHandlerType;
MethodInfo addHandler = ev.GetAddMethod();

Type returnType = tDelegate.GetMethod("Invoke").ReturnType;

ParameterInfo[] parameters = tDelegate.GetMethod("Invoke").GetParameters();
Type[] typeParameters = new Type[parameters.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
{
    typeParameters[i] = parameters[i].ParameterType;
}

DynamicMethod handler = new DynamicMethod(
                        "",
                        null,
                        typeParameters);

//here I need to compile and add my custom source code stored in codeToRun

Delegate dEmitted = handler.CreateDelegate(tDelegate);
addHandler.Invoke(result, new Object[] { dEmitted });
```

Any suggestions? 
thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me why you're fetching the `addHandler` method in the first place. Can't you just call:

```
ev.AddEventHandler(result, dEmitted);
```

? If you've created your delegate correctly, that should be fine, and is simpler than invoking the add handler method directly.

If your question is actually about creating the dynamic method, that's a different matter: you may well want to look at [`CSharpCodeProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) to compile source code into an assembly dynamically. I would treat that as an exercise entirely separate from the event handling part though - get the compilation working, then get the event handler hookup working afterwards.

You may want to look at the source code for [Snippy](http://csharpindepth.com/Downloads.aspx) as an example of how you can use `CSharpCodeProvider` - that's a simple tool I wrote for C# in Depth, which just lets you compile and run snippets of code.

Comment: Ok, I've make it simple according to your suggestion.
But now the question is, how may I add to the body of the delegate the code I want to execute (the one stored in codeToRun)? With the help of CSharpCodeProvider? I didn't find examples doing that.